# dragable element in textarea (like a html editor)

Tags: jquery, html, textarea

i searched the whole intetnet for it but i couldn't find it so far so,
i need a dragable input within a textarea of a texteditable div, the dragable textarea has to be part of the text and after submiting the textarea it has to be findable in te text.
it has to be a bit like a html editor.

```
<div class="editable" contenteditable="false" style="width:300px; height:50px; border:1px solid silver; background-color:#FFF;">text text text                      
                    <input type="text" disabled="true" /> <img src="any url"/>
                </div>
```

in this code the image is dragable inside the text but not the input

thanks...
EDIT:
i need to have a textarea with a input inside it that can be sortable trought the text inside the textarea.

Answer (score 0):

This should work if I understand your question right:

HTML:

```
<div class="sortable-wrapper">
<ul id="sortable-list">
<div class="ui-state-default">
<textarea></textarea>
</div>
</ul>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$( "#sortable-list" ).sortable();
$( "#sortable-list" ).disableSelection();
```

Comment: not really the input had to be dragable in the text together with the text in the textarea

Comment: I don't understand what you want, can you be a bit more clear?

Comment: i need to have a textarea with a input inside it that can be sortable trought the text inside the textarea.

Comment: Wrap the input type in either a div or span (depending on which would be valid) and apply the draggable event on that.